# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql

One of our applications (Running on Server 2008 R2) uses a domain service account to connect to our SQL 2005 database (also running on Server 2008 R2).  On occasion, when the application attempts to contact the database, we receive an error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

I am not showing any equivalent errors on either the SQL server or the Domain controllers.  Has anyone run into a similar problem?  Can anyone point me in the right (or any) direction?

Comment: What's the SPN for this host and service, and what should it be?  That's usually the cause - a missing or incorrect SPN.

Comment: @HopelessN00b But I wonder what would make this intermittent?

Comment: @RyanRies Oh yeah, I missed that... I guess that either the service account getting locked out, or the domain not being reachable temporarily would do it, but we can only guess.